# How do I fix these LibreOffice unmet dependencies?

Tags: libreoffice, dependencies

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libreoffice: Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed               
             Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: ttf-dejavu but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: ttf-sil-gentium-basic but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libreoffice-filter-mobiledev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:3.4.4~) but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-base-core : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
libreoffice-calc : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
libreoffice-draw : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
libreoffice-gnome : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
libreoffice-gtk : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
libreoffice-impress : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
libreoffice-math : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
libreoffice-writer : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
python-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade Libreoffice via a PPA? Because Ubuntu 11.10 comes with Libreoffice installed, so you don't have to install it manually by yourself.

Comment: did you try apt-get -f install. as it said down below

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are mixing `libreoffice` from `oneiric` and `libreoffice-core` from `oneiric-updates`. Make sure that you have "Updates" enabled in "Software Sources".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I'm essentially lazy with installations, so I just did the following:

Open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Just type "`Y`" when prompted.